# Run java project on Ubuntu using terminal

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Currently i have java project with multiple classes and the main class is importing some of them.
The project is working fine when i import it in VScode and run it on windows, but when i upload it on server and run the main class from command line i get erros.

my main class is :

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

import test.model.FileInfo;


public class PublishApiDemo {

    /**
     * Token domain name.
     */
    private static String domain = "xx";

    /**
     * clientId
     */
    private static String clientId = "xxxxx";

    /**
     * clientSecret
     */
    private static String clientSecret = "xxxxx";

    /**
     * App ID.
     */
    private static String appId = "xxxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        // Obtain the token.
        String token = GetToken.getToken(domain, clientId, clientSecret);

        // Query app information.
        GetAppInfo.getAppInfo(domain, clientId, token, appId, "en-GB");

        // Submit for review.
        SubmitAudit.submit(domain, clientId, token, appId);
    }

}
```

the error im getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        GetToken cannot be resolved
        GetAppInfo cannot be resolved
        SubmitAudit cannot be resolved

        at test.PublishApiDemo.main(PublishApiDemo.java:40)
```

i have tried to run

```
javac filename.java 
java filename
javac -cp lib.jar PublishApiDemo.java
```

**EDIT:**

after i have imported the classes at the top like this :

```
import test.SubmitAudit;
import test.GetToken;
import test.GetAppInfo;
```

now im getting another error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        HttpPost cannot be resolved to a type
        HttpPost cannot be resolved to a type
        JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
        JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
        StringEntity cannot be resolved to a type
        StringEntity cannot be resolved to a type
        CloseableHttpClient cannot be resolved to a type
        HttpClients cannot be resolved
        HttpResponse cannot be resolved to a type
        HttpStatus cannot be resolved to a variable
        JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
        JSON cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that error is not with the xOS you use, it's in java code itself.
how and where you intend to see the result? where is the print command after the method call?

Comment: when i run the main class in VScode i see the response in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the classes you are importing have dependencies on the items listed in your runtime errors.  You will need to include the jar files that the test.* classes use in the runtime classpath.

I use findjar.com to locate common jars given a class.  For example, StringEntity can be found in org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0 which is a jar file called httpcore-4.0.jar.  This may or may not be the one needed though.  If you have source for test.* you can check the import statements to confirm and specify the fully-qualified import package in the findjar search.

More than likely, wherever you got the test.* classes will indicate what runtime jars you will need in documentation.